# Nextcloud fpm container with nginx on the host

Tags: debian, docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I'm trying to deploy [nextcloud-fpm docker-compose](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud).

But i got this error in my nginx error logs `[error] 28942#28942: *7817 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: my-domain.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://[::]:9002", host: "my-domain.fr"`.

The docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    ports:
      - 9002:9000
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./data/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

The nginx config file :

```
upstream nextcloud {
    server localhost:9002;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-domain.fr;


    return 301 https://my-domain.fr$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-domain.fr;

    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    root /home/baptiste/nextcloud/data/nextcloud;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    # The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location = /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
        #include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

        # Avoid sending the security headers twice
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;

        # Enable pretty urls
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass nextcloud;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # Adding the cache control header for js, css and map files
    # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
    location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
        # have those duplicated to the ones above)
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
        # this topic first.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;
        #
        # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
        # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
        # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
        # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
        # could take several months.
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap|mp4|webm)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.fr/privkey.pem;
}
```

Finaly, the rights on the folder `/home/baptiste/nextcloud/data/nextcloud` is set to uid 33 which is the uid of www-data inside the nextcloud-fpm container.

I can't find why this doesn't work properly. Is anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is pretty old, but since I ran into the same issue and couldn't find an answer anywhere, I leave my solution here for reference.

The problem is the different path to the files inside the docker container and on the host itself. In the php block of the nginx config `$document_root` points to `/home/baptiste/nextcloud/data/nextcloud` while php-fpm in the container can't access it as this path doesn't exist. There the path is `/var/www/html`. My solution was to replace `$document_root` with the path in the nextcloud container, `/var/www/html`.